# Error 503 Service Unavailable when using localhost with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm posting this to save others a day wasting time trying to solve this.

My PC froze during a build and publish of my web application, so I had to switch the machine off and back on again.  This coincided with a Windows Update being applied when the machine restarted.

After this I could not run the web application in Visual Studio, getting a Error 503 Service unavailable.

After trying everything mentioned here and elsewhere on the web, I noticed an app_offline.html file sitting in the solution folder.  The file was empty.

I deleted the file and of course it all starts working.  This file had been left during the incomplete build process.

So, hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the app_offline.html file if one has been left after a broken build and publish process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS. Then go to IIS and click Application Pool, then click on default application pool and the clik on START.